# Replacing one div with another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs in ma page. I want to show one and hide another. All happens in the same place ( position in page). I used replacewith. It works fine. But on the replaced div no jQuery actions/click works. So which is the best way to do this?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, bind to the element upon its creation, use .live()  but it depends on other factors. Can you show us some code?

Comment: +1 @Liam, it's clear `.live()` is required here.

Comment: .live isn't required. Look@my answer

Comment: Hmmmm, I mis-understood a pretty important part of the question... my bad :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the show(), hide() methods would work fine here. Is there a reason that you need to replace the entire div?

```
$("#div1").hide();
$("#div2").show();
```

You could also do it with some style and call the toggle method to animate it a bit:

```
$("#div1").toggle("slow");
$("#div2").toggle("slow");
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can also toggle both with a single line of code:

```
$("#div1, #div2").toggle("slow");
```

Comment: The toggle can even be `$("#div1, #div2").toggle("slow");`: http://jsbin.com/egujoj

Comment: @James Hill - can i toggle the text of the button when its clicked?

Comment: @pradeep, Yes. If you're using an input (type="button") then use: `$("#myButton").attr('value', 'Toggle div 1');`. If you're using a `<button>` tag then use `$("#myButton").html('Toggle div 1');`

Comment: @James Hill - i am using the <button> but when i do like $("#myButton").html('Toggle div 1'); its replacing just the 1st time and next time nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#show_first").bind('click', function(){
         $("#first").show();
         $("#second").hide();
    });
    $("#show_second").bind('click', function(){
         $("#second").show();
         $("#first").hide();
    });

    $("#inside").bind('click', function(){
        alert('works (first)');
    });
    $("#inside2").bind('click', function(){
        alert('works (second)');
    });
});
</script>
<div id="first" style="display:none"><span id="inside">Inside <-- click </span> -- first</div>
<div id="second" style="display:none"><span id="inside2">Inside <-- click </span> -- second</div>
<div id="show_second">Show second</div>
<div id="show_first">Show first</div>
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/ca6bf.php)